# Can't I use input function inside def function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, function

Why doesn't the following code work?

```
def function(namel,locationl):
    name = input("Your name: ")
    location = input("Location: ")
    return name+location
print(function(namel=name,locationl=location))
```

It showed the error : name and location not defined.

Comment: If `name` and `location` are inputted inside the function what purpose do `namel` and `locationl` serve as arguments? Regardless, when the line `print(function(namel=name,locationl=location))` executes `name` and `location` are indeed not defined

Comment: Yes, you can. Whether you *should* is an entire different question

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the parameters *namel* and *locationl* while assigning them to name and location which is not defined. Also I don't see why you are passing parameters if no logic is being applied on the function.